# How to copy entire webpage containing all HTML, SCript and CSS in Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSOUP to copy a webpage like this:

```
public String fetch(String url1) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();
        String document=doc.toString();
        Elements links = doc.select("link");
        Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
        for (Element element : links) {
            document += element.absUrl("href");
        }
        for (Element element : scripts) {
           document += element.absUrl("src");
        }
        return document;
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But it's only fetching HTML content, while it should fetch HTML, CSS and SCript.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the `link` and `script` elements, and basically adding their URL (`href` and `src` attributes respectively) to the output.

Instead I think you should be recursively calling `fetch` to add the *content* of these URLs.

Note that this won't per se generate a viable HTML document, as you can't just inline the CSS and Script like that.